# Babel transpiled code issue with Chai Things

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, chai, babeljs

I'm running tests on a Node Project coded in ES6 (using Babel). However I get an issue when using Chai Things.

Here is a test file (`array.js`):

```
var chai = require("chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(require('chai-things'));

describe('Array', function() {

   it('Test array', function(cb){
       [{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
        cb();
   });

});
```

Results:

1. The test pass correctly when run without babel
   `./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec`
2. **The test fails when run with babel:**
   `./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require babelhook --reporter spec`

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/array.js:8:51)
```

How can I fix this issue to make the test pass using Babel ?

Comment: This looks quite like your previous question. Is there any difference?

Comment: The question is more succint and better-written though. You might want to edit your previous one to simplifiy the test demo snippet :-)